# Create view in stored procedure in a file

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

Im required to put both create view and stored procedures in one sql file. And another file with just executing the stored procedured. I've tried the method below but it doesn't work. How can i do that?

1st file:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_top10Products
AS

exec ('CREATE VIEW vw_top10Products as
    SELECT Top 10 p.productID, p.productName as Product_Name,    inv.quantitySold as Quantity_Sold,
           (inv.sellingPrice - inv.costPrice)*inv.quantitySold as Profit 
    FROM Product p JOIN
         Inventory inv
         ON p.productID = inv.productID
    ORDER BY Profit Desc')

BEGIN
select *
from vw_top10Products;
END
GO
```

2nd file:

```
EXECUTE usp_top10Products;
```

Comment: WHY do you create the view in your stored procedure? You should either design a procedure which gives you expected output or just a view. the combination makes no sense for me (or do we need more information?)

Comment: Very strange approach I suppose. Do you really need to create a view in stored procedure? Your procedure will try to create a view every time you're running this sp, so first time it can succeed, but definitely will fail every time after it. So why the procedure is needed?

Comment: `doesn't work` - elaborate. it works for me...

Comment: My end result is to print out the top 10 products when i run the stored procedure, what will be a better to do it?

Comment: You don't need view to do it. Just use the same code from view in sotred procedure directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid to create a View in a Stored Procedure. If you only have to print out your `SELECT` you only need to do the `SELECT`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_top10Products
    AS

        SELECT Top 10 p.productID, p.productName as Product_Name,    inv.quantitySold as Quantity_Sold,
                   (inv.sellingPrice - inv.costPrice)*inv.quantitySold as Profit 
        FROM Product p JOIN
                 Inventory inv
                 ON p.productID = inv.productID
        ORDER BY Profit Desc

        GO
```